# django. ZoneInfoNotFoundError

Tags: python, django

Не могу зайти в панель администратора на Django. Страница не открывается, пишет, `A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator`. Как быть?

Сервер на локальном хосте. Пытаюсь зайти на http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ но выдает эту ошибку. А в терминале пишет:

> zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key UTC' [31/Mar/2023 16:26:54] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59.

Как можно исправить ситуацию?

Comment: А вы пробовали эту ошибку забить в поиск google, например? там первый же ответ вам должен помочь

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71058888/zoneinfonotfounderror-no-time-zone-found-with-key-utc